# modifying camera's perspective projection

Tags: ios, camera, projection, scenekit

In a perspective projection, equally sized objects nearer to the camera appear larger than those farther away. Is it possible to affect the distortion of perspective projection? The picture shows what I mean.[image]

The default perspective projection can sometimes result in unrealistic distortion when the camera is near the object and it would be great if I could set some property to modify it.  I have my fingers crossed for `projectionTransform()`and `setProjectionTransform(_:)` but I have no idea how to use them. `usesOrthographicProjection` is unfortunately too extreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! What you are looking for is the field of view. It's available [as a property of the camera](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNCamera_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNCamera/xFov) and is pretty much equal to the Zoom on its real life counterpart.

A low field of view means your camera is very zoomed in. That way, there will be very little perspective, but you will have to **move the camera further back** (since you are zooming in).

On the opposite, if you set a high field of view, the camera will be very zoomed out until it starts looking like a GoPro or any "wide angle" camera. There will be a lot of distortion and you'll need to move the camera closer.

[Here's a crash course on perspective for virtual cameras](http://greyscalegorilla.com/blog/tutorials/choosing-the-correct-focal-length-in-cinema-4d-cameras/). It's about Cinema 4D and they use "Focal Length" instead of field of view, but overall the concept is the same.

Comment: I read about xFov before posting question but completely misunderstood it. really great crash course btw. "never stick with standard lens!!" :D